# Erratic innerHTML behavior. Text disapearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I am trying to update the `<p>` tag using jquery, however, when I click the 'submit' button the text I am inserting with innerHTML quickly disappears. UNLESS I use Firefox, in which case it seems to work -IF- I insert the alert box.  This sounds to me like some sort of timing problem.  But I am not sure quite what it is or how do fix it.  Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#addCourse').live("submit", function(){
        //alert("Submit Function.  hours = "+$('#hours').val());
        document.getElementById('hrs_planned').innerHTML = 'HOURS = '+INIT_PLANNED_HRS+2;//($('#hours').val())+' GPA';
     });                
     document.getElementById('hrs_planned').innerHTML = 'HOURS!! = '+INIT_PLANNED_HRS+' GPA';
});
```

and the html

```
<li><h3>Planned Courses</h3><p id = "hrs_planned"> gpa </p></li>
```

Comment: More than likely your page is refreshing due to not preventing the default submit from happening.

Comment: +1. Add `return false` to the submit handler.

Comment: @thg435 Okay, how would you do that?

Comment: I tried adding return false to the function, with no change in behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `return false`;

Also use `on()` instead of `live()` if you are using jQuery 1.7 as `live()` has been depricated. See [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for details.
If you are using jQuery 1.6.x or earlier use `delegate()` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addCourse').on("submit", function(e) {
        //alert("Submit Function.  hours = "+$('#hours').val());
        document.getElementById('hrs_planned').innerHTML = 'HOURS = ' + INIT_PLANNED_HRS + 2; //($('#hours').val())+' GPA';
        return false;
    });
    document.getElementById('hrs_planned').innerHTML = 'HOURS!! = ' + INIT_PLANNED_HRS + ' GPA';
});​
```

..or if that fails you can try to use `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addCourse').on("submit", function(e) {
        // prevent default submit behaviour
        e.preventDefault;
        //alert("Submit Function.  hours = "+$('#hours').val());
        document.getElementById('hrs_planned').innerHTML = 'HOURS = ' + INIT_PLANNED_HRS + 2; //($('#hours').val())+' GPA';

        // prevent event from bubbling up
        e.stopPropagation;
    });
    document.getElementById('hrs_planned').innerHTML = 'HOURS!! = ' + INIT_PLANNED_HRS + ' GPA';
});​
```

Comment: actually I switch it to on and it seems to be working correctly now! thanks!